# Will an Intel Pentium D run Windows XP 64-bit?

Tags: windows-xp

I have a Pentium D 3.0GHz CPU on an Asus P5GDC-V motherboard.

Can I install Windows XP 64-bit corporate edition on that machine?

Answer (score 2):

According to Intel YES

[Pentium D Specs](http://ark.intel.com/products/27518/Intel-Pentium-D-Processor-930-4M-Cache-3_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)

Comment: But you will probably be *very* unhappy with the performance. The 64-bit instruction set implementation on the Pentium D was a rush job and performance is truly awful.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to run Windows XP 64 bit. Get a newer version.

Yes, it is a 64bit CPU therefore XP 64 will run.

Comment: Might help to let him know why - XP 64 bit had horrid drive support amongst other things didn't it?

Comment: XP 64 is not really maintained, the drivers barely exist and it has another kernel then XP, which might cause further software problems.